# Localhost Can't assign requested address

Tags: linux, macos, localhost

I use MacOS 10.14.6 and few days ago I faced with a problem on my computer with localhost.
Rubymine can't connect to database with an error "java.net.NoRouteToHostException: Can't assign requested address (Address not available).". Also when I run puma server on 0.0.0.0:3000, browser can't open page on this address, and when I run server on 127.0.0.1:3000, browser can't open page on this address too, but can open on localhost:3000. I ran ping and got this output:

````
PING 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1): 56 data bytes
ping: sendto: Can't assign requested address
ping: sendto: Can't assign requested address
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
ping: sendto: Can't assign requested address
Request timeout for icmp_seq 1
ping: sendto: Can't assign requested address
Request timeout for icmp_seq 2
ping: sendto: Can't assign requested address
Request timeout for icmp_seq 3
^C
--- 127.0.0.1 ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100.0% packet loss```
````

Answer (score 12, accepted):

WARP was the cause of the problem. Issue started after disabling the app. Disabling and reboot or enabling the app resolved the issue.

Comment: As it turns out, yes. Just enabled it and worked. Was trying to diagnose the issue for 2 days. Didn’t have a clue that this would work.

To add more light on the issue, iPv6 protocol still works perfectly fine. So if you use that instead of iPv4, you’re good to go.

Disabling WARP only affects iPv4 in my knowledge.

Comment: @Okatawa Wow! You saved my day man! 

Comment: Yes, the issue from WARP after a long investigation!!! thank you.

Comment: What do you do if you don't want to keep WARP enabled?

Answer (score 0):

This was how I solved this problem in my case on a Mac:

On your terminal:

```
ifconfig lo0
```

if 127.0.0.1 isn't listed, then add it:

```
sudo ifconfig lo0 alias 127.0.0.1
```